# Parse string that defines a user-specified format for a file name in Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm trying to allow users to define a string such as `'%X/%P_%D_%d.txt'` where each format code `%X`  corresponds to a given variable in Python. This format is then used to specify the file name and path. Parsing is similar to datetime's strptime(), but they have a pretty rigid base structure it seems and do it via regex. I was thinking of linking the format code and the variable with a dictionary, i.e.

```
fdict = {r'%X' : 'X001', r'%P' : 'Part5', r'%D' : 1, r'%d' : 2}
```

(the values are just placeholders for variables). But honestly can't find any examples of anything similar and it seems like regex might not be the right way to approach this. Are there any modules that would work? Or better keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An f-string might work well here:

```py
fdict = {r'%X' : 'X001', r'%P' : 'Part5', r'%D' : 1, r'%d' : 2}
filename =  f"{fdict['%X']}/{fdict['%P']}_{fdict['%D']}_{fdict['%d']}.txt"
print(filename)  # X001/Part5_1_2.txt
```

You could also use `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
fdict = {r'%X' : 'X001', r'%P' : 'Part5', r'%D' : '1', r'%d' : '2'}
filename = "%X/%P_%D_%d.txt"
regex = r'|'.join(fdict.keys())
output = re.sub(regex, lambda m: fdict[m.group()], filename)
print(output)  # X001/Part5_1_2.txt
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the user to not have to worry about the format of the dict. I think for my use case just using re.sub for all format codes might work, though it's not very pretty.

Comment: @Luke I have given you a regex option which might meet your expectations.

Comment: Thanks! That is considerably nicer than the for loop I was just trying and a lot quicker as well :) I was stuck on not doing regex before, but that ended up a lot simpler than I was expecting.